# What is the command in vi editor to covert column of numbers into row?

Tags: vim

This is currently  what i am dealing with:

```
$cat k    
23
22
35
24
42
:
:
36
```

I have file like this and I want to use vim convert it like this.

```
22,23,35,24,42,8,......,36
```

Please Help

Comment: do those empty lines exist in your file?

Answer (score 8):

**option 1:**

you could execute:

```
:%s/\n/,/
```

this leaves an extra comma `,` at the end of the line, you could `$x` to remove it.

this will do the substitution without the extra ending comma:

```
:1,$-1s/\n/,/
```

**option 2:**

use my Join plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4516

with it you just need:

```
:%J ','
```

**option 3 (awk)**

if awk is accepted by you too, you don't need handle the comma by your self, jst let awk add them automatically for you. it could be as easy as:

```
awk -F"\n" '$1=$1' RS="" OFS="," file
```

Comment: :1,$-1s/\n/,/ this option extraordinary thank you we can also try this awk 'NR>1{s=s$0",";next}END{sub(/..$/,"",s);print s}1' k but your second solution was extraordinary Thanks

Comment: and also how do i get my original output back

Comment: @user2321739 if awk is acceptable too, it could be much easier than the line in your comment. check my updated answer.

Comment: @user2321739 `u` in vim is `undo`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is overkill for your use case, but the https://github.com/salsifis/vim-transpose/ plugin can do that too. Moreover it coverts column**s** (of numbers) into row**s**.

With the plugin installed, you can achieve this as follow:

```
let g:transpose_csv_default_separator = ','
TransposeCSV
```

It would moreover convert

```
23,14
22,64
35,12
24,43
42,65
:,:
:,:
36,19
```

into

```
23,22,35,24,42,:,:,36
14,64,12,43,65,:,:,19
```